# I am trying to set a back arrow in my toolbar but I can't get it to take you to the previous page when clicked

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working with xamarin.android.
I have tried to use the SetNavigationOnClickListener method but I have not been able to implement it. Could someone tell me what to set so that when I click the arrow it returns me to the previous page?
XML:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Code:

```
var toolbar = FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.SetNavigationOnClickListener(//NOT WORK);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Back button in Toolbar not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712893/back-button-in-toolbar-not-working). If not, google `xamarin android toolbar back button` shows other similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create a toolbar again. Use the code below would show the back button in toolbar. And then override the `OnOptionsItemSelected` event to handle the back button click.

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        var actionBar = SupportActionBar;
       
        actionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        
    }
    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```